# Cumulative distribution function of the median

Tags: statistics, cumulative-distribution-functions

If X is the sample median from a poisson distribution, is there a way for me to find the cdf of the median i.e $F(y) = P(X <= y)$. I have never seen the cdf in terms of the median, always as a random variable and hence I am stumped.

Comment: Note that while the median itself (when it's well-defined) is a constant, the _sample median_ **is** a random variable.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I know I understood that.

Comment: Then "I have never seen the cdf in terms of the median, always as a random variable and hence I am stumped." makes no sense to me.  Do you know how to find CDF of other order statistics?

Comment: @BrianMoehring What I meant was that I've never seen the random variable for the cdf in terms of the sample median, always just a standard random variable.

Comment: Well, can you write cdf of the first order statistics? If you say about sample median, do you have a sample from Poisson distribution?

Comment: @NCh I have 3 i.i.d random variables from the poisson distribution. Ultimately I want to find out if the sample median is biased or not.

Comment: @43zombiegit Look at cdf of order statistics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic

Comment: @NCh I looked at that earlier but couldn't see what part of it was relevant to my question. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I do not know what you need since your question is unclear. What is sample median? Is not it an order statistic?

Comment: @NCh Ultimately I want E[X] where X is the sample median with $X_1, X_2, X_3$ being i.i.d from a poisson distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d. with $\mathrm{Pois}(\lambda)$ distribution. Then the probability mass function of the $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ order statistic is given by
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X_{(k)}=m) &= \mathbb P(X_{(k)}\leqslant m) - \mathbb P(X_{(k)}<m)\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\binom nj((1-F(m))^j(F(m))^{n-j} - (1-F(m)+f(m))^j(F(m)-f(m))^{n-j}),
\end{align}
where $F(m) = \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}$ is the distribution function of $X_1$ and $f(x) = \frac{\lambda^m}{m!}e^{-\lambda}$ is the probability mass function of $X_1$. Letting $n=3$ and $k=2$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X_{(k)}=m) &= \sum_{j=0}^{1}\binom 3j\left(\left(\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty \frac{\lambda ^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}\right)^j\left(\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}\right)^{3-j} - \left(\sum_{k=,}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}\right)^j\left(\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}\right)^{3-j}\right)\\
&=\frac{\Gamma (m+1,\lambda )^2 (3 m!-3 m \Gamma (m,\lambda )+\Gamma (m+1,\lambda ))}{(m!)^3}+\frac{2 \Gamma (m,\lambda )^3}{\Gamma (m)^3}-\frac{3 \Gamma (m,\lambda )^2}{\Gamma (m)^2}
\end{align}
I don't know how to simplify this further, unfortunately.